# How to print api calls per thread with nvprof

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nvprof, nvvp

I am profiling a CUDA application and dumping the logs to a file say target.prof

My application uses multiple threads to dispatch kernels and I want to observe the api calls from just one of those threads. 
I tried using `nvprof -i target.prof --print-api-trace` but this does not print the thread_id.

When I open this file with the visual profiler, I can see which API calls were launched from which thread. How can I access the same information using the command line profiler?

**Edit**: View in the visual profiler

[image: Visual Profiler showing multiple threads]

Answer (score -2):

Are GPU threads launching those kernels or CPU threads? if cpu threads then use the option `--cpu-thread-tracing on`.

Comment: CPU threads. I tried using `nvprof -i target.prof --cpu-thread-tracing on --print-api-trace` This still does not show output the thread information. I also tried using this option while recording the logs and that still does not work.

Comment: I tried `nvprof --cpu-profiling on --cpu-profiling-thread-mode separated ./a.out`. I am getting the cpu threadIDs. I used `std::async` to launch the kernels

Comment: I tried profiling my application with these options and it just seems to hang. I have also attached a screenshot of the visual profiler screen. It shows api calls from 2 threads. However, when I just use `nvprof --print-api-trace` it only shows me 3 colums - time, duration and the call name

Comment: Have you tried this command `nvprof --cpu-profiling on --cpu-profiling-thread-mode separated ./a.out`

Comment: Yes, when I run my program with that, it hangs

Comment: Try this one `nvprof --cpu-profiling on --cpu-profiling-thread-mode separated --cpu-profiling-scope function  -i target.prof`.

Comment: This again prints the same results as before

Comment: could you show me the output dump. to be clear are you looking for cpu thread Ids?